# Use FBML to embed a custom video player / video on facebook walls?

Tags: facebook, flash, flv, fbml

I'm trying to get a video (flv) or an swf video player to work on Facebook walls, however no matter what I do - facebook posts the raw fbml and ignores the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<fb:swf 
    swfsrc='http://www.domain.com/flv_player/Main.swf' 
    imgsrc='http://www.domain.com/large1.jpg' 
    allowscriptaccess=”all” 
    flashvars='config=http://www.domain.com/playerConfigEmbed/2179.xml' 
    width="384" height="283" />
```

I've also tried fb:flv

```
<fb:flv src='http://www.domain.com/files/file.flv' width='400' height='300' title='my movie' color='#FFBB00' salign='r' img='http://www.domain.com/thumbs/large1.jpg' scale='showall'/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with Open Graph meta tags. I've written a short tutorial on how to do it right here: http://ahrengot.com/tutorials/custom-video-player-on-facebook/

This method will also allow you to have HTML5 fallback for iphones, which will even work in the Facebook iPhone app - My example is set up with HTML5 fallback that shows that functionality as well.

Answer (score 2):

try that one:

```
<fb:swf
   swfbgcolor="000000"
   imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;"
   swfsrc='http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=12941088&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0'
   imgsrc='http://lojke.pl/PapayaLearn/video_link.png'
   width='400' height='302'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insure yourself of placing the label
`<Fb:fbjs-bridge />`
 Before creating your `<fb:swf />`
 This will serve you to create a bridge to communicate with the Flash.

Then:

```
<Fb:swf
 Swfsrc ='http: // your domain/yourflash.swf '
 Width = '550' height = '400' align ='center ' />
```

If these working with free Hosting the most probable thing is that Facebook prevents that your SWF is visualized.